# faulting module msvcr100.dll,exception code 0xc0000417

Tags: java, jvm-crash

When I run a self written java program and after a certain time the JVM crashes, but no JVM log is saved.

The only thing I find is following event in Windows Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application java.exe, version 7.0.670.1, time stamp 0x53d28725, faulting module msvcr100.dll, version 10.0.40219.1, time stamp 0x4d5f0c22, exception code 0xc0000417, fault offset 0x0008af3e, process id 0x14fc, application start time 0x01cfb572d3b64c7f.
```

Any ideas where it could come from ?

Comment: Maybe you need to reinstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package?

Comment: Reinstall of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package didn't help.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which is your java version? Could it be a bug?

Comment: OS = Vista SP2 Java 7.0.670.1
It also occurs on java 8

String thing is that JVM doesn't log anyting even when -XX:ErrorFile is added

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to reproduce the situation. Can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own program was using a 3rd party program.
An update of that program did solve the issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Which 3rd party program do you talk about? How does it relate to Java? I encountered the same problem on a Window 7 system. MS C++ Redistributable Package already (re)installed with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If reinstalling MS C++ 2010 package doesn't help, does it run without error on another machine?